# DataNucleus: "IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant" -- how to fix

Tags: java, enums, jdo, datanucleus

I'm working with an inherited a MySQL dB schema that I can't change.  I am trying to use DataNucleus (JDO) with it.

I have the following in the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `vendors` (
    `vendor_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
    `registration_method` ENUM('Company','Basic Upgrade','Website','Secure Admin','Unknown') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`vendor_id`),
    ...
```

And I have defined a POJO to work with it:

```
@PersistenceCapable( table="vendors" )
public class VendorRec {
        ...
    public static enum registration_method_enum {
        Company( "Company" ), Basic_Upgrade( "Basic Upgrade" ), Website( "Website" ), Secure_Admin( "Secure Admin" ), Unknown( "Unknown" );
        private String registration_method;
        registration_method_enum( String registration_method ) {
            this.registration_method = registration_method;
        }
        public String getRegistration_method() {
            return this.registration_method;
        }
    };
        ...
    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer vendor_id;
        ...
    private registration_method_enum registration_method;
        ...
```

I am using DataNucleus's JDO interface to retrieve this class:

```
Set<Integer> vendorIds = new HashSet();
        ...
Query q = persistenceManager.newQuery( VendorRec.class );
q.declareParameters( "java.util.Set vendorIds" );
q.setFilter( "vendorIds.contains( vendor_id )" );
q.setOrdering("vendor_fname ascending, vendor_lname ascending");
final Iterator<VendorRec> vendorIt = ( ( List<VendorRec> )q.execute( vendorIds ) ).iterator();
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant ca.vendorlink.app.schema.VendorRec.registration_method_enum.Secure Admin
        ...
```

Well duh!  Of course there isn't an enum constant "registration_method_enum.Secure Admin"!  Spaces are not allowed!  But that's the dB definition I've inherited... :-(

Suggestions for fixing this problem?  Is there a different way I should be defining the enum?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: by convention, Enum class names should be camel cased, like this: `RegistrationMethodEnum`. I'm not sure how to solve your problem -- it may involve creating and registering a customer type converter -- something like this: http://datanucleus.blogspot.com/2013/08/configuring-persistence-of.html